# How easy is it for computers to compute in a 4th Dimension (or more)?

Tags: complexity-theory

I know its very hard to show a human what the 4th dimension would look like and the mind can't even comprehend more dimensions, but what about a computer?

How many "dimensions" can a computer handle?

Or maybe a better way to ask, does computing power exponentially increase when extra dimensions are added?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are confused by physical manifestation of (space-time) dimension versus mathematical definition of dimension.

Mathematics (the language of computing) is all about modeling and generalizing reality. Therefore, much more can be represented and calculated that cannot be seen or even does not exist in the real world. Same goes for dimensions.

In **1 dimension** (which also doesn't exist in reality), position is represented with just one number, say $x_1$. We visualize it as a line.

In **2 dimensions** (which also doesn't exist in reality), position is represented with two numbers, say $(x_1,x_2)$. We visualize it as Euclidean plane.

$\vdots$

In **n dimensions** (which existance in reality we may not know), position is represented with $n$ numbers, say $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$. We cannot visualize it if $n$ is too large.

You can see how these constructions of representing dimensions are all similar. So are the mathematical operations on them similar and thus we can compute in any dimension (with or without a computer). For a simple example, we can add two $n$-dimensional vectors as
$$(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n) + (y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n) = (x_1+y_1,x_2+y_2,\ldots,x_n+y_n)$$

The important thing here is that - if something fails to be interpreted with our biological senses, it doesn't mean that we are unable to define it and model its behavior mathematicaly.

We can use our models for a lot of maybe unobvious purposes later on. For example, a word "bike" can be interpreted as a 4-dimensional vector ('b','i','k','e') where those characters are in fact represented as numbers in a computer. We can then with no problem calculate how close (meaning how similar they are) is this 4-dimensional vector to some other 4-dimensional vector ("cats", "bite", "work",...). Something down this line is, for example, used in Google when it guesses what you wanted to type even if you made a typo.

And lastly;

- **No, it is not hard for computers (nor for humans!) to compute in arbitrary dimensions** (as long as there is enough time to do it). Handling a 7-dimensional vector is no harder than handling 7 separate numbers.
- **How many dimensions can a computer handle depends on its architecture and performance capabilities**, but in theory it could compute with arbitrary dimensions.
- Complexity describes a property of an algorithm and we defined algorithms for vector manipulations the same for all dimensions. It is in fact the purpose of complexity theory to give us information about large (enough) inputs/dimensions. When we say, for example, that some algorithm is in $O(n^{2.3728638})$, it means that it has this complexity for all (large enough) $n$, where $n$ is the size of input.
  **So does complexity exponentialy increases when new dimension is added? No, it doesn't change at all.**
  Execution time, on the other hand, does change and changes in the way it is described inside $O()$ when you plug in desired dimension $n$. But that varies depending on the algorithm (what are you trying to compute), rather than dimension itself.

Answer (score 1):

Computers can handle arbitrarily many dimensions. Indeed, machine learning often involves problems with many dimensions (in some cases, infinitely many!).

As a simple example, if $(x,y,z),(x',y',z')$ are two 3D vectors (the vectors point from the origin to the given coordinate), then the angle $\theta$ between them is
$$
\cos^{-1} \frac{xx'+yy'+zz'}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\sqrt{x'^2+y'^2+z'^2}}.
$$
This can easily be generalized to $n$ dimensions: the angle between $(x_1,\ldots,x_n),(y_1,\ldots,y_n)$ is
$$
\cos^{-1} \frac{x_1x'_1 + \cdots + x_nx'_n}{\sqrt{x_1^2 + \cdots + x_n^2}\sqrt{x'^2_1 + \cdots + x'^2_n}}.
$$

Computers don't have geometric intuition; but they can compute formulas. If whatever you want to do in high-dimensional space has a formula, then the computer can handle it. As mentioned in one of the other answers, many of these formulas are best stated in the language of *linear algebra*.

Problems tend to become more difficult as the number of dimensions increase, and this is an issue in some applications. But the difficulty here is quantitative rather than qualitative.

Answer (score 0):

Classical computers usually do multi-dimensional calculations through [matrix algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations#Matrix_algebra) whose complexity hovers around O(n^3). There are other representations of multiple dimensions such as complex numbers, quaternions, octonians, and sedenions, but those are used far more in mathematics than in computer science.

Comment: Complex numbers do get used.

Comment: Ya, I am simplifying a lot here. I listed it because most people will recognize and understand it immediately but not the ones afterward. Quaternions are used in graphics and quantum computing, but it gets way more theoretical with octonians and septonians. E.g yes, but in a different way.